# How to fix the apk build error. Please......?

Tags: android, kotlin, apk

I am getting following error:

> e: /storage/emulated/0/AndroidIDEProjects/My Application1/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication1/ui/theme/Theme.kt: (21, 5): Unresolved reference: MaterialTheme

> e: /storage/emulated/0/AndroidIDEProjects/My Application1/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication1/ui/theme/Theme.kt: (31, 28): Unresolved reference: colors

> e: /storage/emulated/0/AndroidIDEProjects/My Application1/app/src/main/java/com/example/myapplication1/ui/theme/Theme.kt: (34, 25): Type mismatch: inferred type is ColorScheme but Color was expect
> ed

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.0.0"
    id("kotlin-android")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 31
    namespace = "com.example.myapplication1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.myapplication1"
        minSdk = 21
        targetSdk = 31
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "11"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.3.2"
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha05")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.0.5")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.5")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.5")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.0-alpha03")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")

    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0")
}
```

I haven't tried anything since I don't understand